# How to configure Redis_sentinel with flask app?

Tags: flask, redis, redis-sentinel, redis-cache, flask-caching

Currently I am using Redis for my Flask  app and having the configuration as below.

```
redis_config = redis.StrictRedis(
host='myhost',
port=myport,
db=0,
username='',
password='mypass',
ssl=True,
ssl_cert_reqs='required',
ssl_ca_certs='redis_certs/ca.crt',
ssl_certfile='redis_certs/client.crt',
ssl_keyfile='/redis_certs/client.key',
```

)
and then passing the same to cache config.

```
CACHE_CONFIG = {
'CACHE_TYPE': 'redis',
'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 60 * 60 * 24, # 1 day default (in secs)
'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'someprefix',
#'CACHE_REDIS_URL': 'redis://xyz:1234/1',
'CACHE_REDIS_HOST': redis_config,
```

}

If I want to change the config to redis_sentinel instead of Redis for better availibality. I am not able to understand the configuration mentioned in Flask-cachig doc.

```
CACHE_KEY_PREFIX
CACHE_REDIS_SENTINELS
CACHE_REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER
CACHE_REDIS_PASSWORD
CACHE_REDIS_DB
```

and how to configure along with SSl? I am new to redis and did not find anything helpful resource online.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new with Redis too, and now I'm still checking on this.
I never try with SSL yet, so this will only connect to redis sentinel only. What I was do is this config.

```
CACHE_CONFIG = {
  'CACHE_TYPE': 'redissentinel',
  'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'someprefix',
  'CACHE_REDIS_SENTINELS': [('your_sentinel_host1', 26379), ('your_sentinel_host2', 26379), ('your_sentinel_host3', 26379)],
  'CACHE_REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER': 'your_master_name_from_sentinel'
}
```

I'm testing with [this docker](https://github.com/xavierchow/docker-redis-sentinel) and it's work.